# javascript not working wen invoking IE using VBA

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, click, html-select

I am trying to click on a dropdown Options list via VBA programmatically. But the selection of the option works but the JavaScript associated to the click doesn't work. 
I tried the both options  - .click & .focus.
But both these doesn't invoke the associated javascript.
See below the code

```
Set ElementCol = appIE.Document.getElementsByTagName("option")

For Each obj In ElementCol
    If obj.innerHTML = "abc" Then
     obj.Selected = True
      obj.Focus
      obj.click
    Exit For
 End If
Next obj
```

in IE it's:

```
<select>
  <option value="abc">abc </option>
  <option value="def">def</option>
</select>
```

Comment: "But the selection of the option works but the javascript associated to the click doesn't work. " I don't see any Javascript? It is a lot more straightforward / faster doing this with Javascript or jQuery on DOM Ready with only one line of code than doing this in VBA. I really see no purpose in this.

Comment: well.. am not the developing the site.. just trying to automate a manual form submission via VBA. 

the javascript code wasn't given as i cannot as it violates policy.. its mentioned in the <select onchange=*> section...

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
Sub DOM_SetSelect()

Dim oIE         As Object
Dim oBody       As Variant
Dim oSelect     As Variant

Set oIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
oIE.Visible = True
oIE.Navigate ("http://www.tizag.com/htmlT/htmlselect.php")
While oIE.ReadyState <> 4
    DoEvents
Wend

Set oBody = oIE.Document.body
Set oSelect = oBody.GetElementsByTagName("select")(0)
oSelect.selectedindex = 2

End Sub
```

If you want to set by value, then use

```
oSelect.value = "CA" 'in the demo website that I've added
```

Comment: thanks a lot... @kim and santhosh... i wil check and let you know... thanks again!

Comment: @kim.. being new to vba got a doubt.. we are only getting the elements by tag/ value. but we aren't invoking the click event right.. can you please help me on the same. (i just tried this code and see no changes)

Comment: What happens is that you  look up and change the value of the elements in the DOM directly, rather than triggering a piece of Javascript (click event) to handle this for you. If you don't see changes, perhaps you are not changing the correct value; just click right mouse click on the page and have a look at the source HTML.

Answer (score 0):

FireEvent is used to trigger the javascript event attached to any element.

Try this

`obj.FireEvent("onclick")`

You may even try this

`obj.execScript "onclick()", "JavaScript"`

Comment: @kim gysen i tried your ans.. obj.fireevent("onclick").. but i see no response... :( 

do we have to use onclick or onchange.. coz' the code invokes javascript onchange event... but wen i used it showed up error :(

please guide me.. thanks in advance!

Comment: @SamuelMathews Can you post the actual viewsource of obj.